# Dot separate align numbering

Tags: numbering, align

When you're numbering equations steps with align is it possible to separate the problem numbering like (problem #).(step) like they did here? [image: example]

Comment: How is your `problem` environment defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the `amsmath` documentation ([PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
  \begin{align}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]